# Check that all items of IEnumerable<T?> has the same value using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5, ienumerable

I have a nullable type, e.g. `SomeEnum?` and a set of values, e.g. `IEnumerable<SomeEnum?>`.

How to check that all items has the same value using LINQ (and get this value)?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
public static bool AllEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> values) where T : struct
{
        if (!values.Any()) return true;
        T? first = values.First();
        return values.Skip(1).All(v => first.Equals(v));
}
```

EDIT: To get the value you could return a tuple (success, value) like this:

```
public Tuple<bool, T?> AllEqual<T>(IEnumerable<T?> values) where T : struct
{
    if(! values.Any()) return Tuple.Create(true, (T?)null);
    T? first = values.First();
    bool equal = values.Skip(1).All(v => v.Equals(first));
    return Tuple.Create(equal, equal ? first : (T?)null);
}
```

or you could use an out parameter instead:

```
public static bool AllEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T?> values, out T? value) where T : struct
{
    value = null;
    if (!values.Any()) return true;

    T? first = values.First();
    value = first;

    return values.Skip(1).All(v => first.Equals(v));
}
```

Comment: This is preferable for LINQ to Objects because it will bail as soon as it finds one value that isn't equal. In LINQ to Entities and such, it will cause 3 round-trips, though.

Comment: It doesn't return the value, note.

Comment: @stripling - all the answers on this question short-circuit. And EF will treat this as L2O anyway, as it doesn't use Queryable unless the interface is IQueryable

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Good point. I didn't know whether Distinct was lazy-evaluated for sure. Should've assumed it was.

Comment: @stripling - and as a point of note, since not all sequences are repeatable, even in L2O you should avoid multiple reads

Comment: I would be happy to use 4.0 but unfortunately locked with 3.5 (added the appropriate tag)

Comment: What does `!values.All()` do?

Comment: @abatishchev - Assuming you meant `!values.Any()` that checks for an empty sequence - this implementation assumes that all the items in an empty sequence are empty and the 'value' is null. You may want to throw an exception instead. `values.All(...)` returns whether each item in the sequence meets some condition - in this case whether each other item is equal to the first (and hence are all equal).

Answer (score 24):

```
data.Distinct().Count() == 1;
```

works well too.

Comment: Great idea. And can be wrapped in the same extension method as Lee's way

Answer (score 10):

Lazy and returns true for empty sequences:

```
public static bool AllEqual<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, out T value)
{
    using (var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            value = default(T);
            return true;
        }

        value = enumerator.Current;
        var comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!comparer.Equals(value, enumerator.Current))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding an intermediate list like Distinct and multiple iterations  like the first answer, which some sequences don't support. Definitely the best implementation in this list.

Comment: I agree with Mike - really good solution. But doesn't use LINQ, as question's author asked.

Comment: @realsonic It does "use LINQ" in the sense that you can call it as `something.Select(...).AllEqual()`. The only problem here is that while it correctly returns `true` for empty sequences, it also returns `default(T)` for the value in that case, so an empty sequence is indistinguishable from a sequence full on nulls. It probably should have two `out` parameters, the second one to say that there were elements in the first place.

Answer (score 6):

```
var value = data.Distinct().Single();
```

(which will throw an exception if there isn't exactly one unique value, otherwise it will return that value)

If you don't want exceptions:

```
var few=data.Distinct().Take(2).ToList();
if(few.Count==1) {
    var value = few[0];
    ...
}
```

Comment: `Take(2)` will throw an exception if `Distinct()` returns 1-length collection, will it not?

Comment: @abatishchev: No, it won't. It works on a "best-effort" basis.

Comment: @abatishchev Take(n) is take *at most*, not take *exactly*

Comment: @abatishchev - also note these are sequences, not collections (until ToList). A subtle distinction, perhaps - until you get high volumes...